# Using different scopes for same binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, ninject

I have this binding in my NinjectControllerFactory:

```
    private void AddBindings()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

And it works well for request to controllers, only one unit of work is instantiated.

But when I inject UnitOfWork to my SignalR Hub class the problem is that all method calls in SignalR are in the same request scope, and same instance of UnitOfWork is used all the time while user is connected.

So, I want to use something like: `ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InScope(ctx => MyHubClass);` so it gets disposed every time.

But can I somehow use this binding only for injection to HubClass, and the first one for all other requests?

Comment: It is possible to use custom scopes, see https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ninject has a extension method called:
.WhenInjectedInto(Type type)

Where you can set which object to inject when injecting in the specific type.
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

So, then you could do

```
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
ninjectKernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto<MyHubClass>().InScope(ctx => ...);
```

Hope that helps.
Sorry, if I mistyped something I haven't got my VS open